# What does "They" in "They were" refer to?

Tags: barbie-2023

In a phone call, Dan from the FBI informs Aaron at Mattel about a peculiar situation
involving Barbie and Ken dolls acting as real people in Santa Monica, and seeks Mattel's
assistance to handle it. After the call, Aaron is left worried, recalling a similar
incident from the past:

> Aaron:  About ten years ago a woman named Skipper turned up in Key
> West at some family’s home and asked to babysit the kids... She then
> tried to take their toddler surfing. **They** were able to straighten
> it out and keep it under wraps. But this is serious.

What does "they" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"They"** are the Mattel Corporation, protecting people from discovering that their intellectual property is actually real.

The [original screenplay](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/b/tt1517268/Barbie-2023-screenplay.pdf) has a very slightly different wording that makes this clearer. It's "we", not "they".

> **AARON DINKINS:** *This happened once before.*
>
> Popping up from ANOTHER cubicle, three cubicles away:
>
> **AN EVEN YOUNGER MATTEL EMPLOYEE:** *What?! When?!*
>
> **AARON DINKINS:** *About ten years ago a woman named Skipper turned up in Key West at some family’s home and asked to babysit the kids... She then tried to take their toddler surfing. **We** were able to straighten it out and keep it under wraps.*
> (grave)
> *But this is serious.*